# Combine date, hits.hour & hits.minute field

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I would like to combine the date, hits.hour & hits.minute field into one date-field that can easily be read by Tableau for visualization.

At the moment the date is a string and the hits.hour & hits.minute are integers.

In the end the date should be something like YYYY-MM-DD & hh:mm.

Atm I converted the date to a string but I dont know how to combine the fields now, or in general if this first step was correct.

Best,
Pascal

```
SELECT 
fullVisitorId,
visitId,
date,
CAST (hits.hour as string) AS hour,
CAST (hits.minute as string) AS minute,
totals.transactions ,
hits.item.productName,
FROM [X.ga_sessions_20180221] 
WHERE hits.hitNumber =1
GROUP BY 
  fullVisitorId, visitId, date, hour, minute, hits.item.productName, totals.transactions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to concatenate selected values

```
SELECT 
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    CAST(date as string) +' & ' + CAST (hits.hour as string) + ':' + CAST (hits.minute as string) AS datetime,
    totals.transactions ,
    hits.item.productName,
FROM [X.ga_sessions_20180221] 
WHERE 
    hits.hitNumber =1
GROUP BY 
  fullVisitorId, visitId, date, hour, minute, hits.item.productName, totals.transactions
```